# Extend HiddenFor Templates in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I thought `Html.HiddenFor` could use Templates like `Html.DisplayFor` or `Html.EditorFor`. Unfortunately the method doesn't accept a `TemplateName` like the others.

I know, the workaround would be to use a DisplayFor/EditorFor Template which has HiddenFors. But I would like to find out how to extend the `Html.HiddenFor` method. Anyone?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are mislead by wrong analogy. `HiddenFor` corresponds exactly to the `<input type="hidden"/>` tag. Just like `TextBoxFor`, `CheckBoxFor` etc. These methods are not designed to use templates. `DisplayFor`/`EditorFor` on the other side are specially created to be used with templates defined in the project. Thus what you are asking for is not possible out-of-the-box.

However you can always define your own overload for `HiddenFor` with whatever set of parameters and whatever logic you might require.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload which accept additional parameter - `htmlAttributes`. And you can use it for add some attributes to the result tag.

Also the second way is to create razor partial view in one of the folders

```
~/Areas/AreaName/Views/ControllerName/DisplayTemplates/TemplateName.cshtml
~/Areas/AreaName/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/TemplateName.cshtml
~/Views/ControllerName/DisplayTemplates/TemplateName.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/TemplateName.cshtml
```

with name `HiddenInput.cshtml`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do, you create it *as an editor template*, because as [Andre pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17545944/3198973), `HiddenFor` is equivalent to the helper methods like `TextBoxFor` and `CheckboxFor`.

It's likely that you'll want to have an actual editor too, so place your *real* editor under `~/Shared/EditorTemplates`. We're going to put our "hidden editor" under the controller you wish to use it on.

```
~/Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates/ModelName.cshtml
```

Lets say we have a `Person` model.

```
public class Person
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

We'll create a partial view.

```
@Model Person

@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.First);
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Last);
```

And then we'll pretend we have a model that contains a `Person` as a property. From our main view, we call our "hidden editor" like so.

```
@Model Foo

@Html.EditorFor(f => f.Person)
```

Easy peasy lemon squeezy. A bit hacky, but it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for this how to, but as I said in my question, I know already that this is a possible workaround :-)

Comment: This wasn't for you @float. This was to save the next guy like me who googles and finds this Q/A an absurd amount of time.